# Request for new 'tax' tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

It is tax return season and a 'tax' tag is in need ;)

I submitted two tax-related questions today, but did not have the tag I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a [taxes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) tag to [What version of TurboTax do I need if I have investments, 401 K, and the ROTH IRA?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30754/what-version-of-turbotax-do-i-need-if-i-have-investments-401-k-and-the-roth-ir).